# how to install voltDB on virtual 3 nodes cluster

Tags: voltdb

I'm currently trying to learn about voltDB so i'm trying to install the community version mon a virtual 3 nodes (matser, node1, node2) cluster using ubuntu 16.04 as OS on Oracle VirtualBox.

But when i tried to start voltDB, here what i got as error on node1 and node2:

------------------ node 1 ---------------

```
master@node1:~/Bureau/voltdb$ bin/voltdb start --host=master
```

Initializing VoltDB...

_    __      ____  ____  ____ 
| |  / /**_  / / /_/ __ / __ )
| | / / __ / / __/ / / / __  |
| |/ / /*/ / / /*/ /*/ / /*/ / 
|_**/____/*/_*/_____/_____/

---

Build: 8.3.2 voltdb-8.3.2-0-gb4ab2b9-local Enterprise Edition

Licensed to: VoltDB Trial User

Loaded node-specific settings from voltdbroot/config/path.properties

Connecting to the VoltDB cluster leader master/192.168.56.104:3021

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

------------------- node 2 --------------------------

```
master@node2:~/Bureau/voltdb$ bin/voltdb start --host=master
```

Initializing VoltDB...

_    __      ____  ____  ____ 
| |  / /**_  / / /_/ __ / __ )
| | / / __ / / __/ / / / __  |
| |/ / /*/ / / /*/ /*/ / /*/ / 
|_**/____/*/_*/_____/_____/

---

Build: 8.3.2 voltdb-8.3.2-0-gb4ab2b9-local Enterprise Edition

Licensed to: VoltDB Trial User

Loaded node-specific settings from voltdbroot/config/path.properties

Connecting to the VoltDB cluster leader master/192.168.56.104:3021

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

WARN: Joining primary failed: Connexion refusée retrying..

---

For recored, i used my own deployement configuration which took 2 sites per host and 3 hosts and k-factor=0.

```
<deployment>
       <cluster hostcount="3" sitesperhost="2" kfactor="0"/>
       <httpd enabled="true"> 
              <jsonapi enabled="true"/>
       </httpd>
</deployment>
```

Comment: Could you show us how exactly you started the master node?

Comment: master@master:~/Bureau/voltdb$ bin/voltdb init --config=examples/voter/deployment.xml       
master@master:~/Bureau/voltdb$ bin/voltdb start --count=3  --host=master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these nodes are set up on different VMs on the same machine, then it looks like you did everything correctly. However, there could be an issue with the VMs themselves, where they do not currently network together. In other words, this might not be a VoltDB issue, but an issue specific to your VMs.

To test this, I recommend starting a 1 node VoltDB cluster on one of your VMs. Then, use the "sqlcmd --servers=The_VM_with_VoltDB_Running" command on one of your other two VMs. If sqlcmd is unable to connect this way, then there is a networking problem with your VMs that can be solved by looking up how to set up a network between Oracle VirtualBoxes.

Full Disclosure: I work at VoltDB.